# How do I obtain the following layout in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to obtain the following layout in android:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a recyclerview, a horizontal recyclerview to be precise. You can get tons of tutorials for that. To make it, you can just go along with how you would normally create a recycler view, but make your xml file code for recycler view as:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
```

The `android:orientation="horizontal"` makes the magic happen.

Otherwise you can also do it progrmatically like:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(
new GridLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext(), rows, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```